# Python equivalent for the matlab A(:,1)' and A(:)

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am converting MATLAB code to Python Numpy. I am referring this doc
http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users

Below is the two MATLAB lines,

```
X = A(:,1)'; 
R = repmat(X(:),1,6);
```

Where A is two dimensional matrix

This is my converted python lines

```
X = A[:, 1].conj().transpose()
R = np.tile(X[:], (1,6))
```

I have two queries,

1. `X = A(:,1)';` - In this line, is the quotes (') refers to `.conj().transpose()`
2. is this `X[:]` right equivalent for `X(:)` or  is it `X.flatten(1)`?

To be more clear, actually I am trying to understand the MATLAB code,

1. `X = A(:,1)';` - In this line, is the quotes (') refers to transpose?
2. `X(:)` - what it means in MATLAB?

Comment: Python programmers will have an easier time answering the question if you explained what the expected output is for a sample input. They may not know matlab.

Comment: To get the transpose, you can use np.transpose() or the .T property of a numpy array. x[:] is equal to x (no flattening going on)

Comment: I didn't know the expected output. I m trying to understand the MATLAB code. If you can explain what the  A(:,1)' and X(:) line doing in MATLAB will be great

Comment: `'` is conjugate transpose in Matlab (to just transpose you use `.'`). `(:)` means flatten (returns a column vector). But here `X = A(:,1)` is already flattened (row vector), so `X(:)` just transposes that into a column vector; it is the same as `X.'`. See [online example](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fUcFWIdpQwUjB2FrBRMFUwSzWmstRw0rHUJMrAigFYapzRWhYAQX01P//BwA)

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks, It is helpful.  You can move the above details from comments to answer section as it is the answer :)

Comment: @Navarasu Done.

Comment: A couple of important differences.  MATLAB is always 2d (or higher); `numpy` can reduce dimensions to 1 (or even 0d).  `x[:]` does nothing, except make a new view.  And for a 1d `ndarray` transpose doesn't change anything.

Comment: Yes x[:] does nothing. Even X.flatten(1) does nothing. In this case, X.reshape(6,1) or X.transpose is doing the same job of  MATLAB X(:). i.e moving all element to column vector. Here 6 is no of rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's define an example `A`:

```
>> A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
```

`'` is [conjugate transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html). To just [transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) use `.'`.

```
>> A(:,1)
ans =
     1
     4

>> X = A(:,1)'
X =
     1     4
```

`(:)` means [reshape (flatten) into a *column* vector](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html). Here `X = A(:,1)'` is already flattened, namely it is a *row* vector, so `X(:)` just transposes that into a column vector; it is the same as `X.'`:

```
>> X(:)
ans =
     1
     4

>> X.'
ans =
     1
     4
```